# How to check whether specific revision is present on some Mercurial remote?

Tags: git, shell, version-control, mercurial

In Git SCM I'm using the following command to check whether a specific revision is present on some remote:

```
git fetch <remote> <revision> -q --dry-run
```

If the exit code of the command is zero that means the revision is present on the remote.

For Mercurial I tried the following command:

```
hg pull <remote> -r <revision> -q
```

It works but the problem is that it actually pulls the revision if present on the remote, but not locally. Is there an equivalent of the `--dry-run` option for Git, or some other way to do it in Mercurial which does not perform pulling of the specified revision, but only checks whether it is present on the remote?

Comment: You could write a mercurial hook that rejects the transaction during the pull, but I believe that will mess with the exit status as well (though I am not actually sure about this). But why does this matter? Why not allow the revision to enter the local repository?

Comment: @torek Because I need it from a script which needs only to do some checks without changing the state.

Comment: In that case, clone the repository, pull, and delete the clone. But note that `hg pull` without `-u` won't touch the *work-tree* at all, just the repository itself.

Comment: @torek This is highly inefficient. I need the command to execute relatively fast because it is part of a larger program and if I do it this way it will dominate the run time.

Comment: Yes, it's terribly inefficient, even when using the local-clone-hard-link method. If you seek efficiency, consider just inspecting the commit's hash ID: fetch works by comparing hash IDs.

Comment: @torek If I understood you correctly you are proposing to fetch the logs for all branches and to search for the revision in them? This is still a much more complex operation than the single command way which is applicable for Git...

Comment: That's what `hg pull` is doing, really: it calls up the other Mercurial repository, and that repository lists out the hash IDs that you'd see in `hg log` with a format that just prints the full hash ID. The local Mercurial and the other one converse: *I don't have that, send it* or *I do have that one, no need to send it (nor any of its ancestors because having that one implies that I also have all its ancestors)*. The result of this conversation determines which revisions Mercurial brings over. Git does the same thing: its protocol is a bit different, but the two Gits exchange hash IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg in -r REV`

`-r --rev REV [+]       a remote changeset intended to be added`

> ```
> Returns 0 if there are incoming changes, 1 otherwise.
> ```