# How to get a list of all branches containing specific revisoin in Mercurial?

Tags: git, command-line, version-control, mercurial

To get a list of all branches containing a specific revision in *Git* according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430285/how-to-check-whether-specific-revision-is-present-on-some-mercurial-remote) *StackOverflow* answer the following command can be used:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

How to get this done with *Mercurial*?

I also want the output to be maximally clean. For example `hg branches` returns also the last revision in the branch:

```
new-branch                     2:657883530997
default                        1:6c8931261776 (inactive)
```

but it will be preferable to return only the names of the branches, each on a new line for easy machine processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mercurial, *only one branch* can contain any specific commit.  Just inspect the commit itself and see which branch it is on; that is the branch it will be on forever.  You can copy that commit to a new commit on a different branch if you like (using `hg graft` for instance) but it will have a different hash ID.

The command `hg log -r rev -T '{branch}'` suffices to extract just the branch name.  The revision specifier can be a relative number or hash ID.

Comment: In this case, is it possible to get a list of branches where the revision is found somewhere in history before the creation of the current branch?

Comment: Yes: find the set of all commits that are descendants of the commit in question (including the commit itself), and ask what their branches are. Run the resulting list through a sort-and-unique pass and you have the set of branch names you want. The revspec for "descendants of commit C" is simply `C::` so `hg log -r C:: -T '{branch}'` lists those branch names; run through `sort -u` and you're good.

Comment: Note that unlike Git's `..` graph operator, Mercurial's `::` graph operator is a fully inclusive one. That is, in `x::y`, instead of `x < rev && rev <= y` (Git's test where < stands for "precedes"), Mercurial is doing `x <= rev && rev <= y`.

Comment: (One should generally use `≺` for precedes, rather than `<`, but I am not sure the operators will show up visually distinct here.)

Comment: @torek: 1. I suppose, log command have to be `hg log -r .:: -T "{branch}\n"` for "branch per line" and piping into sort 2. It will be just nicer as shell-alias (log+sort in one command)